# multidimensional array within input field

Tags: php

I've got a hidden field on my form and I would like to collate and post dates associated to prices in an array so I can use them on another page. At present, I have the following input field defined below.

```
<input name="arrayDatesPrices[]" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo PrintDateTime($recordsCourseWeeks->getField('Start_date'),"d/m/Y"); ?>">
```

and when I do a print_r(arrayDatesPrices) on the following page, it lists all the dates in the array. This works exactly as expected. I have another field called $Price_per_week, and I would like to associate the price to the date. I therefore tried the following.

```
<input name="arrayDatesPrices[]" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo array(PrintDateTime    ($recordsCourseWeeks->getField('Start_date'),"d/m/Y"), array( $Price_per_week) ); ?>">
```

When I do a print_r(arrayDatesPrices)  on the follwoing pages - I get a blank array. Have I got my formatting incorrect or can you do multi dimension arrays input fields?

Comment: Try transferring these things via session instead?

Comment: You are doing <?php echo array(); ?> in your code. It leads to converting array to string which leads to value="Array". You can print_r($array, true) if you need whole array inside value attribute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Try like this..

<input name="arrayDatesPrices[]" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo PrintDateTime($recordsCourseWeeks->getField('Start_date'),
"d/m/Y").':'.$Price_per_week ; ?>"> 

After submit...
$i = 0;
foreach( $arrayDatesPrices as $arr )
{
 list($stat,$wk) = explode(':',$arr);
 $new_arr[$i]['start_date'] = $stat;
 $new_arr[$i++]['wek'] = $wk;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_*` or `serialize` finctions to store structure.
For example:

```
<input name="arrayDatesPrices[]" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo json_encode(PrintDateTime($recordsCourseWeeks->getField('Start_date'),"d/m/Y")); ?>">
```

And in php code u must call:

```
$val = json_decode($_REQUEST['arrayDatesPrices'][$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just put the two values on the field with a ; separator and explode it with you server code after the submit ?

Or think your fields in an other way like :

```
<input name="arrayDatesPrices[0][start_date]" type="hidden" value="<?php  echo PrintDateTime($recordsCourseWeeks->getField('Start_date'),"d/m/Y"); ?>" />
<input name="arrayDatesPrices[0][price_per_week]" type="hidden" value="<?php  echo $Price_per_week ?>" />
```

And incrementing the first parameter for each couple of values